# Is there a proper technical term for (physical) sections in a card file?

Tags: nouns, synonyms, terminology

Imagine having a card-box that contains, for example, vocabulary. It's organized alphabetically and for every letter there's a larger card acting as a separator for words beginning with that letter.

Is there a clear, unambigous word that describes the bundle of cards behind this larger index-card? I'm thinking of `section`, but am unsure if it's really the best word. And maybe the professionals in that field are using a special word for this...

Comment: *Tab Section*, *Section*, or just *Tab*, the last in the sense of contents of a tab section.

Comment: You need to find a librarian old enough to remember when they used card catalogs ... and ask her what this was called then.

Comment: @Kris: Thanks - I'd be happy to accept this as answer if you'd post it such as such ;)

Comment: I am such a person as @GEdgar describes (though not all librarians are female!) and I would agree that _section_ is the best general term.

Comment: @GEdgar We still use the terminology (if metaphorically) though we have moved on to a virtual world. Data files have tabs, Browser windows have tabs, digital documents have tabs ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tab Section**, **Section**, or just **Tab**, the last in the sense of contents of a tab section.

*Use Case*
Loletrazina Church, *[How to Use a Rolodex](https://bizfluent.com/how-8202218-use-rolodex.html)* (bizfluent):

> Arrange the cards alphabetically in your file. For example, place … the cards of people and businesses that start with the letter "A" in "A" section of the Rolodex.